# IN condition and equal condition in a select query return incorrect data

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my query.

```
SELECT *
FROM users 
WHERE 'imported' = 0
AND (id IN (SELECT DISTINCT(author_id) FROM articles) 
OR id IN (SELECT DISTINCT(photographer_id) FROM articles)) 
LIMIT 20
```

I have 2 conditions in my query.

```
'imported' = 0
```

AND

```
(id IN (SELECT DISTINCT(author_id) FROM articles) OR id IN (SELECT DISTINCT(photographer_id) FROM articles))
```

My problem is the data set returned contains rows with `imported = 1` which I don't want.

Comment: The problem is that you are using single quotes for the identifier.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.  I'm voting to close, because this is a typographic error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use backticks for identifiers not single quotes

```
WHERE `imported` = 0
```